# Can I set the response without any data in fuelPHP?

Tags: php, rest, fuelphp

In an API controller that extends `Controller_Rest`

I have in a test function:

```
public function get_arr_exists($arr = array())
{
    if (empty($arr))
    {
        $this->response(array(), 400);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array(), 200);
    }
}
```

I checked rest.php in the fuel core and it requires the first parameter not to be empty else it will return a 404.

But I'd like my app to check if the API responded with ok (200), or not (400). Does the Rest Controller automatically set the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the response status.

```
$this->response->status = 200;
```

Comment: Was wondering if there's a 'cleaner'/'proper' way to do it than work-arounds. (But yeah, that's what I'm doing for now). ;)

Comment: how about `$this->response->status = 200;`

Comment: awesome! Do you wanna edit/reanswer so I can approve for reps? ;)